# Frobenius tower terminates to the identity after finite number of steps

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p>0$ and let $\phi: k \to k$ be the frobenius homomorphism $a \mapsto a^p$.

I want to show that for every element $a \in k$ the sequence $\phi^n (a)$ terminates after a finite number of steps. Meaning $\phi^n (a) = a$ for some $n>0$.

I almost sure this holds but all my attempts to prove this have failed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false if the field is infinite, for example take $K=\Bbb Z_p (x)$, then for all $n\in \Bbb N$:

$$x^{p^n}\neq x$$

However, if the field is finite, say $|K|=p^n$, since $|K^*|=p^n-1$ we have for all $a\in K$:

$$a^{p^n-1}=1$$

i.e.

$$\phi^n(a)=a$$

(So, the sequence terminates and it does it at *the same time* for all $a\in K$).